# How do I use EMR with spark DataFrames

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-spark, pyspark, amazon-emr

I am running an AWS EMR job with spark. My input data is in my S3 bucket (csv files as .gz).

I am trying to filter multiple input files (one month worth of data, 1 file = 1 day) by first reading them in my spark dataframe, do some filtering and writing the result in my s3 bucket.

**My Problem:** I thought spark dataframes are already optimized to run on multiple nodes, but when running my code it only uses one node resulting in long computing time.

My code

```
input_bucket = my-bucket
input_path = '/2019/01/*/*.gz'   #reading all january files
spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("Pythonexample").getOrCreate()
df = spark.read.csv(path=input_bucket+input_path, header=True, inferSchema=True)
df = df.drop("Time","Status")  #keeping only relevant col
df = df.dropDuplicates()
df.show()
data = return_duplicates(df,'ID')  # data = df without unique rows, only duplicates

data.write.format("com.databricks.spark.csv").option("header", "true").save(input_bucket+'/output')
```

my function

```
def return_duplicates(df, column):
    w = Window.partitionBy(column)
    return df.select('*', f.count(column).over(w).alias('dupeCount')).where('dupeCount > 1').drop('dupeCount')
```

**Question:** What should I change?
How can I use Map-Reduce or something similar (parallelize()?) with spark dataframes to use multiple nodes and reduce computing time?

Comment: How do you know that it is not being executed in a parallel way? can you post that info?

Comment: My emr has 3 nodes (1 master, 2 task). while running my code 1 task node has 99% CPU usage the other task node has like 3% CPU usage, which seems wrong to me.

Comment: Could you check how many partitions do you have in your dataframe? Also, if you post the DAG diagram you can see from the SparkUI that may give us more info to help you. Also, how many files are you actually reading from S3?